# Android get external IP

Tags: android, ip, external

I am developing an application in android 2.1 and I want to display the external IP. How could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you consider to be the 'external' IP address?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public void getCurrentIP () {
    ip.setText("Please wait...");  
    try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://ifcfg.me/ip");
            // HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://ipecho.net/plain");
            HttpResponse response;

            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            //Log.i("externalip",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                    long len = entity.getContentLength();
                    if (len != -1 && len < 1024) {
                            String str=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                            //Log.i("externalip",str);
                ip.setText(str);
                    } else {
                            ip.setText("Response too long or error.");
                            //debug
                            //ip.setText("Response too long or error: "+EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                            //Log.i("externalip",EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                    }            
            } else {
                    ip.setText("Null:"+response.getStatusLine().toString());
            }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ip.setText("Error");
    }

}
```

Comment: http://whatismyip.akamai.com/
  great : but use this url with AsyncTask .

Comment: if you are wants json data https://ifcfg.me/json

Comment: thats real awesome thanks for sharing link with all.

Comment: Is the any limit on usage of this URL ?

Answer (score 2):

http://api.externalip.net/ip will return your ip in simple api format

You can read more about getting the external ip here: http://www.externalip.net/api

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to do it programmatically but you could call up a site like http://www.whatismyip.com/ and then strip out the IP from the page.  You might want to find a site that offers an API and supports 3rd party calls.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this code snippet:

```
String ipAddress = null;
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("IP ADDRESS:", ipAddress);
```

Comment: Gets local IP not external IP