# Android - failed to get external IP

Tags: android, ip

I followed this link [Android get external IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077555/android-get-external-ip) .
I am connecting to this website http://www.whatismyip.org/ to get my IP address, however, it keep returning a length of -1.

Any idea why? I am able to open up this site using my browser and it returns my external IP. I am unable to use other websites as they return a proxy IP or some other IP...

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going with that service. Don't check for length cause they don't provide that info but go straight for fetching the ip

so forget about if condition and go for it like this

```
                entity.getContentLength();
                String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                ip.setText(str);
```

Comment: Ok, then what is the purpose of them checking the length? I thought it is used to check if there is any content body...

Comment: the service you use purposely stripped everything to reduce the package load. it is their designed to reduce the traffic load. it is not a bug.